# Orchard CMS 1.4 - Install package failed

Tags: orchardcms

I am unable to install modules in Orchard 1.4.

I get:
Package installation failed: There was an error installing the requested package. This can happen if the server does not have write access to the '~/Modules' or '~/Themes' folder of the web site. If the site is running in shared hosted environement, adding write access to these folders sometimes needs to be done manually through the Hoster control panel. Once Themes and Modules have been installed, it is recommended to remove write access to these folders.

The IIS_IUSRS user have full permissions on App_data, Themes, and Modules.

Server is running Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.5.

The application pool is running .NET Framework 4.0, Integrated Pipeline Mode, and ApplicationPoolIdentity

I turned CustomErrors to Off in Web.Config, but i am not getting a stack trace or anything specific i can use to find the cause.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change the gallery feed URL to http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc/

Comment: How about granting the answer then? ;)

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks. My only note here is to add that as to change the gallery feed URL it was neccessary to add a new feed Settings->Gallery and then to remove the existing one.

Comment: Wow, this really needs to be fixed. I spent 30 minutes trying to fix this on a clean install by messing with permissions before I found this answer.

Comment: This is already fixed. You should have downloaded the latest version.

Comment: It's not fixed if you're upgrading from older versions :-(( Really there should be at least a note in the upgrade process / breaking changes :-(

Comment: It's not linked to the version. It's going to happen whether you're using 1.4 or 0.8, and the upgrade process has nothing to do with it.